# How do I create a user on Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am struggling to make this happen as easy as it should. Everywhere I look it says it is as simple as:

```
$ createuser -P
```

But that will always fail:

```
$ creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
```

I am expecting a prompt so that I can give a name, but it will not show up.

What now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [reading the fine manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html). You supply a user-name

```
createuser -P newusername
```

Personally, I always do it via SQL with [`CREATE USER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html)

Comment: Don't forget the ';' at the end. 

    create user -p user_name;

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

$sudo -u postgres psql

> > > then

postgres=# DROP USER userToDelete

And recreate  your  user

$createuser -P -s -e

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It worked for me

createuser --interactive -P